# How to execute .exe file created on WIndows on other platform using Perl

Tags: windows, perl, unix

Is it possible to execute executable file (.exe) created on Windows on other platform such as Solaris using Perl ? Does Perl have any library to .exe file created on other platform ?

Comment: On Solaris, I've never executed any executable file created on Windows yet. I think I can execute it on Solaris if Wine is used, however I'm finding a way to execute it using Perl.

Comment: I'd like to know if there is any module on Perl to execute it such as Wine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because what the question is asking for and what its author is looking for are not the same thing.

Comment: Let me explain. What I’d like to do is that I execute .exe file created on Windows on Solaris. However I’m not allowed to install Wine; so it would be happy if there was any module for Perl because I’m allowed to install a perl module.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Perl is not an emulator.

You need something to emulate windows (such as `wine`, or a virtual machine with Windows installed)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I want something to emulate Windows on Solaris; I'm finding it...

Comment: [Wine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_(software)) is short for "wine is not an emulator". It works by mapping Windows system calls to local system calls. Doing that in Perl is near impossible.